# if else part not working when read from firebase database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to set the value of the upvote from the recycler view in the firebase database i.e when a user clicks a like button it will increment the value of the upvote by one but if again a user clicks a like button upvote value decrement by one. for this, I tried to switch and if-else but it's not working as it keeps inside of the set Value () part.

```
public class MyRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    public static Context context;

    List<String[]> myDataList;
    List<qna_data> mydataList;
    int values ;

    Long number;
    private Long likeCount;
    private Long downlikeCount;
    private boolean isLiked = false;


    private DatabaseReference qnaRef;
    List<DataSnapshot> dataSnapshotList;
    

    public MyRecyclerViewAdapter(List<qna_data> myDataList) {
        this.mydataList = myDataList;
    }

    public MyRecyclerViewAdapter(DatabaseReference qnaRef, List<DataSnapshot> dataSnapshotList) {
        this.qnaRef = qnaRef;
        this.dataSnapshotList = dataSnapshotList;
    }


    // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public MyRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycleview_post_profile, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        qna_data data = mydataList.get(position);


        context = holder.itemView.getContext();


        holder.question_asked.setText(data.getQuestion_qna_asked());

        holder.time_of_question.setText(data.getQna_timestamp_asked());
        holder.category_choosen.setText(data.getCategory_qna_asked());
        holder.username.setText(data.getUser_qna_name_asked());
        holder.upvote.setText(String.valueOf(data.getUpvote()));
        holder.downvote.setText(String.valueOf(data.getDownvote()));


        holder.upvote_liner.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                number = data.getUpvote();
                String pushkey = data.getPushkey();
                String scholarid = data.getScholar_id();

                likeCount = number + 1;
                DatabaseReference answersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("QnA/Questions").child(pushkey).child(scholarid);

                switch (values) {
                    case 0:
                        System.out.println(values);
                        System.out.println("it is liked");
                        answersRef.child("upvote").setValue(likeCount).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Toast", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
                        values = 1;

                        System.out.println(values);
                        break;


                    case 1:

                        System.out.println("");
                        Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        values = 0;
                        break;

                    default:
                        System.out.println("unknown value of isLiked");
                        break;
                }


//                if (isLiked == false) {
//                    System.out.println("isLiked is false");
//                    isLiked = true;
//                    System.out.println("isLiked is now true");
//                    answersRef.child("upvote").setValue(likeCount);
//
//                    return;
//                } else {

//                    System.out.println("isLiked is true");
//                    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Toast", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                }


            }
        });


        Glide.with(holder.profile_of_users.getContext())
                .load(data.getImage()).into(holder.profile_of_users);

    }
    
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mydataList.size();
    }

    // ViewHolder class
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView question_asked, time_of_question, category_choosen, username, upvote, downvote;
        de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView profile_of_users;
        LinearLayoutCompat linear, upvote_liner;

        AppCompatImageView upimage;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            linear = itemView.findViewById(R.id.answer_question_qna);

            profile_of_users = itemView.findViewById(R.id.profile_qna);

            profile_of_users = itemView.findViewById(R.id.profile_qna);
            username = itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_name_qna);
            time_of_question = itemView.findViewById(R.id.timestamp_qna);
            category_choosen = itemView.findViewById(R.id.category_qna);
            question_asked = itemView.findViewById(R.id.question_qna);

            upvote = itemView.findViewById(R.id.upvote_waala_qna);
            downvote = itemView.findViewById(R.id.downvote_waala_qna);
            upvote_liner = itemView.findViewById(R.id.upvote_linear);
//            upimage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.upvote_button);
        }

        public qna_data getItem(int position) {
            // Get the question object at this position
            DataSnapshot questionSnapshot = dataSnapshotList.get(position);
            qna_data question = questionSnapshot.getValue(qna_data.class);
            question.setPushkey(questionSnapshot.getKey());
            return question;
        }

    }


}
```

I update my code after debugging I got to know that the value of values variable change to 1 but case 1: not running if I use setValue() method but without setvalue() method it working fine

Comment: Where you have intilized values variable ?

Comment: @Maveňツ I initialized values variable at top of code in my Adapter

Comment: then please share the complete code

Comment: @Maveňツ i shared my complete code

Comment: please initialized  values = 0; while declaring it

Comment: @Maveňツ I tried it before but that doesnt work as well

Comment: If you understand Kotlin, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-delete-a-record-from-firestore-on-a-recylerview-left-right-swipe-d65d993f0baf) might help. I know it makes a different operation, but it will help track the click and perform the operation you want.

Answer (score 0):

Since the value of values is never updated in your case 0 code block, it will always execute the case 0 block on subsequent clicks, resulting in the value of likeCount being incremented every time.

To fix this, you need to update the value of values after the case 0 block has executed. You can do this by adding `values = 1;` after `answersRef.child("upvote").setValue(likeCount);` in the case 0 block, like this:

```
       case 0:
            System.out.println("it is liked");
            int likeCount = number + 1;
            answersRef.child("upvote").setValue(likeCount).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Liked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            values = 1;
            break;

        case 1:
            System.out.println("it is unliked");
            int unlikeCount = number - 1;
            answersRef.child("upvote").setValue(unlikeCount).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Unliked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            values = 0;
            break;

        default:
            System.out.println("unknown value of isLiked");
            break;
    }
```

This will ensure that case 1 is executed on the next click after case 0, and vice versa, allowing you to increment or decrement the upvote value as needed.

Comment: dont mind but can you tell whats the difference between your code and mine ??

Comment: [OP](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253163/21317446) have already set value in case 0 and case 1

Comment: I tried but didnt work it keeps updating whenever user clicks.

Comment: @Remo sorry for the confusion. I've updated the code

Comment: @AimanKhan I have updated my code and question please have a look.